# Auto resize of div need to be refreshed to get working

Tags: html, css, jquery-textext

I used textext to make a auto-completion. That input text is not responsive to changing window size anymore. The screen is good at the first time:

[image]

But when I change my browser window all fields shrink except tag (which has textext custom style) it right elements go to that field:

[image]

If I hit refresh that will find its proper position.
Here is the related css for that field:

```
.text-core {
position: relative;
}

.text-core .text-wrap {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-core .text-wrap textarea, .text-core .text-wrap input {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #9daccc;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 1;
    background: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 5px 4px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font: 14px; height : 34px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 34px;
    min-width: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

Please someone help to make that responsive like others. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootstrap grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Put the form with a col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 and col-xs-12 and the buttons with col-lg-6  col-md-12 col-sm-12 and col-xs-12.